# Recursive function for nested dictionary returns None however prints the expected data in function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I have a JSON with many nested dictionaries and list that I need to modify and when I want to find the data it returns no result. However it prints the expected values before the return.

Below a simplified structure of the JSON that I need to work with:

```
nested_dict = {'k': {'component':'media','value':'It is a test'}}
```

My code below:

```
def find_component(data: object, component: str):
    """
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i, k in enumerate(data):
            find_component(data[i], component)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():

            if k == 'component' and v == component:
                print(k, v)
                print('Find Component', data)
                return data
            else:
                find_component(data[k], component)
# Call to the recursive function
res = find_component(nested_dict, 'media')
```

The results of the print are the expected ones:

```
component media
Find Component {'component': 'media', 'value': 'It is a test'}
```

However the result of the data is None

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return find_component`. When you just call it, the result is lost, and the function returns `None` because that's what is implicitly returned by any function that does not explicitly `return` a value.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a couple of `returns`:

```py
def find_component(data: object, component: str):
    """
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i, k in enumerate(data):
            return find_component(data[i], component)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == 'component' and v == component:
                print(k, v)
                print('Find Component', data)
                return data
            else:
                return find_component(data[k], component)
```

Comment: I am new to recursion, so basically I need to return the function in every instance that i don't want to get the results?

Comment: @TMikonos You need to return from every recursive call so the data can be passed back up to previous calls, or else the initial call will never receive the data.

Comment: Basically what @Carcigenicate said, you have to return something every time the function is called.

Comment: It works with the sample data created for this but with the original JSON it stops in the first dictionary instance. It is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Joan Lara, I have found a solution that it works. I needed to check if the result is not None to return the result of the function call, so the code becomes like this:

```
def find_component(data: object, component: str):
    """
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for i, k in enumerate(data):

           res = find_component(data[i], component)
           if res is not None:
               return res
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():

            if k == 'component' and v == component:
                print('I found the component', k, v)
                #print('Find Component', data)
                return data
            else:
                res = find_component(data[k], component)
                if res is not None:
                    return res
```